# Using unset for $_POST -

Tags: php, post, unset

My code has multiple `$_POST` variables.  I like to clean things up and `unset` them after everything has been executed.

I don't want to have to list each `$_POST` out individually.  Is there a good way of `unset` all `$_post` values at once.  I don't want to unset my `$_SESSIONS` or other variables.  Just the Post ones.

Any helpful hints is very much appreciated.

I tried using `unset($_POST);` 
   - but it does not `unset` the values. Thanks

Comment: How are you testing to see if $_POST has been unset? If you were to reload the page the values would be populated again

Comment: @deceze wouldn't that just add an extra array with value `0` ?

Comment: Is there any reason to do this after everything is done executing??

Comment: @Alez What? Why? No, it sets `$_POST` to be an empty array.

Comment: @danronmoon the OP probably uses his $_POST variables only in some place and has finished working with it long before he renders an output. But I agree with you, it doesn't seem necessary in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as it gets. Try this:

```
$_POST = array();
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly - just what I was looking for.  Thanks so much deceze and Jivan